A proof that every natural number is either even or odd.
If $k \in\mathbb{Z}$ is a number, $n$ is said to be even if it is in the form $2k=n$. $2k+1$ is odd and so is $n+1$. Let $Q$ be the set of natural numbers in the form $2k$ or $2k+1$. Obviously $$1 \in Q$$ $$n \in Q$$ $$n+1 \in Q$$ Therefore $Q$ is the set of natural numbers. Q.E.D
Afternotes:
I feel like this proof is incomplete because it relies on n being even instead of n being any arbitrary natural number. But I would love to hear what others think. Thanks!

The command for "is an element of" symbol is "\in". It'll look like this: $\in$

What misses is to show that if $n$ is of the form $2k+1$ , then $n+1$ is of the form $2m$ for some integer $m$ which is however easy.

You’re trying to prove this by induction? That works, but I would make it clear that’s what you’re doing. You should explain the inductive step: $n \in Q \implies n+1 \in Q$. Why is that the case?

You can make your life much easier if you use the usual definition of even and odd : An integer is even if it is divisible by $2$ and odd if it is not divisible by $2$. The law of the excluded middle then immediately proves the claim.

Definitely feels fishy... what is n? They introduced n as: "n is said to be even if it is in the form 2k=n". Thus n is in the form 2k, which means it is even. Fine, but this definition includes 0, -2, -4, -6, ... Then they define Q, whatever. And then they say $n \in Q$ ... I think not.
